# matplotlib cancel legend on axes object

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using an external module which automatically adds a legend to the plot.
I would like to know if there is a way of turning off the legend, something like ax.set_legend(False).

I could fix it by hacking the module but I would rather not do that.

example:

```
 f = plt.figure()
 ax = f.add_subplot(111)

 externalfunction(ax)

 # in the function ax.legend() has been called
 # would like to turn off the legend here

 plt.show()
```

Update:

I have raised a github issue for this 
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2792

Comment: can you make a github issue for this?  It looks like the legend artist is not removable, but it should be.

Comment: is that necessary? I feel that xndrme's answer does what I needed.

Comment: @Anake the suggestion of tcaswell  is for improving the framework for future use, you can use my solution but it shouldn't be that way ;)

Comment: it only _seems_ to do what you need (that is, you can't see the legend so your are happy).  But from the dev side this is very hacky solution, the _correct_ solution is to be able to remove the legend which seems to be not technically possible. (fyi I am a mpl dev)

Comment: @tcaswell Well, maybe you can fix it for all of us :)

Comment: @tcaswell yes you are right it shouldn't be that way, sorry. Also thanks xndrme, I'll add a link to the issue in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the visibility of your legend, try this: `ax.legend().set_visible(False)`

Comment: this regenerates the legend and then makes it invisible.

Comment: @tcaswell (+1 to your comment on the question) I use this hack to hide the legends, it should be an issue on GitHub

Answer (score 4):

This can also be accomplished by setting the `legend_` attribute of the axis to `None`. Note the trailing underscore. E.g.

```
x, y = np.random.randn(2, 30)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.plot(x, y, label="data")
ax.legend()
ax.legend_ = None
```

It sounds like future matplotlib versions will have a more officially-sanctioned method for removing the axis, but this should work in the meantime/if stuck on an older version.